# Control CSS keyframes animation progress with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

Let’s say I have a simple keyframes animation to move a box from left to right:

```
@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    left: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 250px;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to control this animation with a slider ranging from 0-100% in React? Meaning, the animation should always represent the state of the slider. If the slider is moved from 20% to 40% the animation should also be moved from 20% to 40% during that time.

Yes, I know that’s not the intended purpose of keyframes animations but I’d like to find a way regardless.

Here’s a CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/keyframe-experiment-96x5qy

Comment: so you mean what you're tryin to say when you move the scroll bar/slider you have the box move as well and follow it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with style prop change on `box` without `keyframes`

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keyframe-experiment-forked-5mvv0b?file=/src/App.js:0-450)

*Note that I'm using percentage for calculating `left` position, if you want to make it move further, you can modify `left: progress + "px"` with your own calculation*

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Progress: {progress}%</h1>
      <div class="box" style={{ left: progress + "px" }}></div>
      <input
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="100"
        value={progress}
        step="1"
        onInput={(e) => setProgress(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The style modification

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 1s; /*Added transition*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to do it the way you want...

In case you only want to stop the keyframe while moving the range slider try this: [sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/keyframe-experiment-forked-vp7wyy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.animate {
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}
```

App.js:

```
export default function App() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [moving, setMoving] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Progress: {progress}%</h1>
      <p>is moving: {moving ? "true" : "false"}</p>
      <div
        className={`box ${!moving && "animate"}`}
        style={{ left: `${progress}px` }}
      ></div>
      <input
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="100"
        value={progress}
        step="1"
        onInput={(e) => {
          setMoving(true);
          setProgress(e.target.value);
        }}
        onMouseUp={() => setMoving(false)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

After the mouseUp event on the range slider, the keyframe animation starts all over again (from the 0%). You can also define keyframes as CSS in JS and change the values depending on the current position of the slider to start the animation from place where the box was moved.